# Are there any control sets for PHP?

Tags: php, controls

Are there any good control sets that can be used with PHP, like how there are Telerik controls for ASP.Net?

Comment: I unl33tinized it for you. Your welcome.

Comment: I shouldn't have checked the revision history for the original wording. Ow.

Answer (score 0):

Not exclusive for PHP but I like Ext.js

http://www.extjs.com/products/js/

Answer (score 0):

There is Delphi for PHP:
http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-for-php

But it is better not to use it and learn to code by yourself :-)

Comment: Delphi For PHP is a good product, and there is at least one 3rd-party component library.